# Align text as leading in ScrollView - SWIFTUI

Tags: uiscrollview, swiftui

I have a `ScrollView`:

```
    ScrollView {
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            Text("\(userData.username), \(userData.age)")
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .font(Font.system(size:30))
        }
    }
```

The output is:

[image]

I tried flipping the Stack and having the scroll view inside, but I get the same result.

The work around I have is to put it in a HStack and add a Spacer()

```
HStack {
         Text("\(userData.username), \(userData.age)")
             .fontWeight(.semibold)
             .font(Font.system(size:30))
             .padding([.leading])
         Spacer()
}
```

This does the trick but I dont think this is the ideal way. Is this the only way? or is there a better solution to align text vertically in a scrollview?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By default stack container is tight to content, so alignment has no effect.

Here is possible solution

```
ScrollView {
    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
        Text("\(userData.username), \(userData.age)")
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .font(Font.system(size:30))
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // << make screen-wide !!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you just missed a parameter and can do this:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
        Text("\(userData.username), \(userData.age)")
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .font(Font.system(size:30))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another great way of fixing this is to use GeometryReader:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView {
            VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                Text("\(userData.username), \(userData.age)")
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .font(Font.system(size:30))
            }.frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading) //get the width from geometry
        }
    }
}
```

GeometryReader returns a flexible preferred size to its parent layout.
You can use the geometry.size to access width and height of the container.