# SwiftUI ScrollView Alignment

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to align some content inside a `ScrollView`.
I would like to get part of this content centered and another part aligned to the leading of my screen.
I can't understand why my following code isn't working, it seems that my content is centered and doesn't take the whole width.
I did try to set the width, but none has worked.
Any idea on how I could keep my `Text("center")` centered and get my `hello's` list to the left ?

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my current code :

```
struct ReportView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("centered")
                }

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { value in
                        Text("hello \(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(L10n.Tab.Reports.item)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935527/align-text-as-leading-in-scrollview-swiftui

Comment: @KishanBhatiya thanks, it works, but it's still seems weird to have to do that way

Answer (score 0):

Put your content inside Hstack and add a Spacer:

```
ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { value in
    HStack {
        Text("Hello \(value)")
        Spacer()
    }
}
```